# Getting JWT token from the redux-store and configuring the JWT with axios?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, jwt

Currently iam  storing the JWT token in the local storage and sending the token by pulling it from the localstorage like the one in the code below. Is it possible to get the jwt directly from the redux-store rather than from the localstorage.

```
import axios from "axios";
import config from "./config/config.json";

let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fakeTkn"));

var instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.serverURL,
});

instance.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;

export default instance;
```

I have tried importing the store and getting the state.

```
let state = store.getState()
```

Although this gets the state, it gets the initial state which is empty I am also using
redux-persist to persist the store.

Comment: are you dispatching a action to set the token to the state? when you get it? otherwise it will never be on redux, also in actions.create instance you pass the headers without doing this `instance.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"]`

Comment: When a user logs in the jwt is sent along with other info. The jwt is present is the store. It worked when the user signes in but whenever the browser is refreshed the jwt is lost because it gets the initialstate which is empty. I need a way to access the jwt from the store after the initial render ie after redux-persists rehydrates the store.